# Records are getting twice on the view page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am getting twice records on the view page.

```
$data['upcomingForsecondary']=$this->Access_model->upcomingsecondary($data['getLogininfo']->customer_id);
```

Getting the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member_id] => 337
            [first_name] => zxs
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => asd
            [email] => qwe@gmail.com
            [dob] => 22-04-1984
            [phone] => 1231231231
            [landline] => 
            [membershipForTheYear] => 2018-2019
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member_id] => 209
            [first_name] => sdf
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => asd
            [email] => asdas@gmail.com
            [dob] => 24-07-1982
            [phone] => 1231231231
            [landline] => 
            [membershipForTheYear] => 2018-2019
        )

)
```

Now I a passing membershipForTheYear to the model using foreach get the records.

**Controller code**

```
$data['upcomingForsecondary']=$this->Access_model->upcomingsecondary($data['getLogininfo']->customer_id);

foreach ($data['upcomingForsecondary'] as $key => $sec_m_id) {
  $secClubfees[]=$this->Access_model->getfeesFornewyear($sec_m_id->membershipForTheYear);
 }
 $data['newFees'] = $secClubfees;
```

**print_r($data['newFees']) output **

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [clubMembershipFees_id] => 1
                    [clubDuration] => 2019-2020
                    [clubPrimaryMemberFees] => 100
                    [startCutoffDate] => 16-02-2019
                    [endCutoffDate] => 31-03-2019
                    [is_clubFeesActive] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [clubMembershipFees_id] => 1
                    [clubDuration] => 2019-2020
                    [clubPrimaryMemberFees] => 100
                    [startCutoffDate] => 16-02-2019
                    [endCutoffDate] => 31-03-2019
                    [is_clubFeesActive] => 1

                )

        )

)
```

**View code**

```
I tried on view like 

 foreach ($upcomingForsecondary as $key => $secPersonalInfo) {
   /*Displaying personal information which is dislaying perfeclty*/

   foreach ($newFees as $key => $value) {
     foreach ($value as $key => $rows) {

      /*getting issue here. I a getting the twice output*/


              }

      }


}
```

view output I am getting like

```
first member name
fees details
fees details

second member name
fees details
fees details
```

I used multiple foreach that's the issue. I think there some issue on view page or controller .

Would you help me out in this issue?

Comment: What have you tried so far to spot the error?

Comment: @NicoHaase, Thanks for the response. Whatever I tried I added in the question. I am not getting the error. Getting records twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having an idea, what it's all about - And without a clue of codeigniter :) ..

```
foreach ($data['upcomingForsecondary'] as $key => $sec_m_id) {
    $secClubfees[]=$this->Access_model->getfeesFornewyear($sec_m_id->membershipForTheYear);
}
```

Here you throw two results together in an array and lose the relations to the objects in `$data['upcomingForsecondary']`.

Then in the view

```
foreach ($upcomingForsecondary as $key => $secPersonalInfo) {
    // Displaying personal information
    foreach ($newFees as $key => $value) {
        // show the rows
    }
}
```

you loop the two results in `newFees` twice (once per object in `$upcomingForsecondary`).

So you need to relate the inner loop with the outer loop using either `$key` or `$secPersonalInfo`. I can suggest three ways to do that.

#### #1 Hope that the keys are the same:

```
foreach ($upcomingForsecondary as $key1 => $secPersonalInfo) {
    // Displaying personal information
    foreach ($newFees[$key1] as $key2 => $rows) {
        // show the row
    }
}
```

#### #2 Make sure the keys are the same:

```
foreach ($data['upcomingForsecondary'] as $key => $sec_m_id) {
    $secClubfees[$key] = $this->Access_model->getfeesFornewyear($sec_m_id->membershipForTheYear);
}
```

Then use the view code from #1

#### #3 Nest the results:

Controller:

```
foreach ($data['upcomingForsecondary'] as $key => $sec_m_id) {
    $sec_m_id->newFees
        = $this->Access_model->getfeesFornewyear($sec_m_id->membershipForTheYear);
}
```

You don't need `$data['newFees']` in this case.

View:

```
foreach ($upcomingForsecondary as $key1 => $secPersonalInfo) {
    // Displaying personal information
    foreach ($secPersonalInfo->newFees as $key2 => $rows) {
        // show the row
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer #3

Comment: Thanks for the answer..give me some time to check.

Comment: in the #2 should I add  this $data['newFees'] = $secClubfees?

Comment: @user9437856 Yes.. But I just realized that I had a bug in the view. Should be fixed now. Replaced `foreach ($upcomingForsecondary[$key] as $key => $rows)` with `foreach ($newFees[$key] as $key => $rows)`

Comment: Let me try again.Give me some time

Comment: @user9437856 There was another bug in your code, which might not matter in your code. But you shouldn't overwrite the `$key` from outer loop in the inner loop. I renamed them to `$key1` and `$key2`. In real code I would use more appropriate variable names.

Comment: @user9437856 Take as much time as you need. You should understand the problem and validate the solution before you use it.

Comment: I think, your answer is working perfectly.I will accept and upvote you after some time. I am trying to understand your answer. I am inserting data and checking it's working or not using above all the answer.